# Error installing fpm on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ruby, debian, ubuntu-16.04

Installation fails for fpm in an Ubuntu 16.04 machine with error logs below. There was no issue for a long time and there were no changes to apt packages being included.

Packages installed were `ruby-dev`, `gcc` originally for fpm. I also tried with `rubygems`, `build-essential`, `autoconf`, `autogen`, `automake`, `pkg-config`, `libgtk-3-dev` and `apt-utils` but to no avail.

```
sudo gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri fpm
Fetching: cabin-0.9.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed cabin-0.9.0
Fetching: backports-3.11.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed backports-3.11.1
Fetching: arr-pm-0.0.10.gem (100%)
Successfully installed arr-pm-0.0.10
Fetching: clamp-1.0.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed clamp-1.0.1
Fetching: ffi-1.9.21.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing fpm:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.21/ext/ffi_c
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20180209-1204-u28w9m.rb extconf.rb
checking for ffi.h... no
checking for ffi.h in /usr/local/include,/usr/include/ffi... no
checking for shlwapi.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_thread_call_with_gvl()... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl()... yes
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/ffi-1.9.21/mkmf.log

current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.21/ext/ffi_c
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.21/ext/ffi_c
make "DESTDIR="
Running autoreconf for libffi
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.21/ext/ffi_c/libffi/autogen.sh: 2: exec: autoreconf: not found
libffi.mk:6: recipe for target '"/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.21/ext/ffi_c/libffi-x86_64-linux-gnu"/.libs/libffi_convenience.a' failed
make: *** ["/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.21/ext/ffi_c/libffi-x86_64-linux-gnu"/.libs/libffi_convenience.a] Error 127

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.21 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/ffi-1.9.21/gem_make.out
```

========================================

```
cat /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/ffi-1.9.21/mkmf.log .
package configuration for libffi is not found
have_header: checking for ffi.h... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby-2.3.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -lruby-2.3  -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */

"gcc -E -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby-2.3.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC  conftest.c -o conftest.i"
conftest.c:3:17: fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <ffi.h>
/* end */

--------------------

find_header: checking for ffi.h in /usr/local/include,/usr/include/ffi... -------------------- no

"gcc -E -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby-2.3.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC  conftest.c -o conftest.i"
conftest.c:3:17: fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <ffi.h>
/* end */

"gcc -E -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby-2.3.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/local/include conftest.c -o conftest.i"
conftest.c:3:17: fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <ffi.h>
/* end */

"gcc -E -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby-2.3.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/ffi conftest.c -o conftest.i"
conftest.c:3:17: fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <ffi.h>
/* end */

--------------------

have_header: checking for shlwapi.h... -------------------- no

"gcc -E -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby-2.3.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC  conftest.c -o conftest.i"
conftest.c:3:21: fatal error: shlwapi.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <shlwapi.h>
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby-2.3.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -lruby-2.3  -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
conftest.c: In function ‘t’:
conftest.c:13:57: error: ‘rb_thread_blocking_region’ undeclared (first use in this function)
 int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))rb_thread_blocking_region; return !p; }
                                                         ^
conftest.c:13:57: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))rb_thread_blocking_region; return !p; }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby-2.3.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -lruby-2.3  -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
/tmp/ccv7JcIW.o: In function `t':
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.21/ext/ffi_c/conftest.c:14: undefined reference to `rb_thread_blocking_region'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: extern void rb_thread_blocking_region();
14: int t(void) { rb_thread_blocking_region(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for rb_thread_call_with_gvl()... -------------------- yes

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby-2.3.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -lruby-2.3  -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
conftest.c: In function ‘t’:
conftest.c:13:57: error: ‘rb_thread_call_with_gvl’ undeclared (first use in this function)
 int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))rb_thread_call_with_gvl; return !p; }
                                                         ^
conftest.c:13:57: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))rb_thread_call_with_gvl; return !p; }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby-2.3.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -lruby-2.3  -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: extern void rb_thread_call_with_gvl();
14: int t(void) { rb_thread_call_with_gvl(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl()... -------------------- yes

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby-2.3.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -lruby-2.3  -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
conftest.c: In function ‘t’:
conftest.c:13:57: error: ‘rb_thread_call_without_gvl’ undeclared (first use in this function)
 int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))rb_thread_call_without_gvl; return !p; }
                                                         ^
conftest.c:13:57: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))rb_thread_call_without_gvl; return !p; }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby-2.3.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -lruby-2.3  -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: extern void rb_thread_call_without_gvl();
14: int t(void) { rb_thread_call_without_gvl(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

extconf.h is:
/* begin */
1: #ifndef EXTCONF_H
2: #define EXTCONF_H
3: #define HAVE_RB_THREAD_CALL_WITH_GVL 1
4: #define HAVE_RB_THREAD_CALL_WITHOUT_GVL 1
5: #define HAVE_FFI_PREP_CIF_VAR 1
6: #define USE_INTERNAL_LIBFFI 1
7: #define RUBY_1_9 1
8: #endif
/* end */
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is failing on installing the `ffi` gem. You need to get that to install then try again. You probably want the ffi library for your system so I would try

```
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
```

then

```
gem install ffi
```

then retry. If it doesn't find the `ffi.h` files after that then just figure out where the headers are installed and use a flag to include it in the `gem install ffi`

Comment: Good, this worked for me.
I had problems with `gem install ffi -v '1.9.21'` but the error was the same.